# sietmap.xml inaccessible in a site created with orchard. How to fix it?

Tags: orchardcms

I just published a website that I created using orchard cms. I added sitemap.xml to the root folder but can't access it via browser.
I am guessing that I probably need to modify web.config  file but I am not sure how.

EDIT:
Here is my webconfig. I don't know how to format it properly here. I am accessing sitemap.xml at `woodworkingoc.com/sitemap.xml` but get 404.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- 
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="log4net.Config" value="Config\log4net.config" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="Orchard.Mvc.ViewEngines.Razor.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        <add namespace="System.Linq" />
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic" />
        <add namespace="Orchard.Mvc.Html" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
  <!-- 
        Set default transaction timeout to 30 minutes so that interactive debugging 
        is easier (default timeout is less than one minute)
  -->
  <system.transactions>
    <defaultSettings timeout="00:30:00" />
  </system.transactions>
  <system.web>
    <!--<trust level="Medium" originUrl="" />-->
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="360" />
    <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
    -->
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" batch="true" numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart="250" optimizeCompilations="true">
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".csproj" type="Orchard.Environment.Extensions.Compilers.CSharpExtensionBuildProviderShim" />
      </buildProviders>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <remove assembly="System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <remove assembly="System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <remove assembly="System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <remove assembly="System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <remove assembly="System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <remove assembly="System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <remove assembly="System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <remove assembly="System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <remove assembly="System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <remove assembly="System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <remove assembly="System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <remove assembly="System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <remove assembly="System.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <remove assembly="System.ServiceModel.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <remove assembly="System.WorkflowServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <remove assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <remove assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <remove assembly="System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
    -->
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Users/Account/AccessDenied" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.
    -->
    <customErrors mode="On">
        <error statusCode="404" reirect="/" />
    </customErrors>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Linq" />
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic" />
        <add namespace="Orchard.Mvc.Html" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
      <!-- see below -->
      <clear />
       <add path="robots.txt" verb="GET" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" /><!--allow sitemap.xml and robots.txt to be served-->
       <add path="/sitemap.xml" verb="GET" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="WarmupHttpModule" type="Orchard.WarmupStarter.WarmupHttpModule, Orchard.WarmupStarter, Version=1.0.20, Culture=neutral" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
  -->
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WarmupHttpModule" />
      <add name="WarmupHttpModule" type="Orchard.WarmupStarter.WarmupHttpModule, Orchard.WarmupStarter, Version=1.0.20, Culture=neutral" />
    </modules>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Script">
      <!-- clear all handlers, prevents executing code file extensions, prevents returning any file contents -->
      <clear />
      <!--add entries for sitemap.xml and robots.txt-->
      <add name="Robots" path="robots.txt" verb="GET" modules="StaticFileModule" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
      <add name="SiteMap" path="/sitemap.xml" verb="GET" modules="StaticFileModule" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
      <!-- Return 404 for all requests via managed handler. The url routing handler will substitute the mvc request handler when routes match. -->
      <add name="NotFound" path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
    <!-- Prevent IIS 7.0 from returning a custom 404/500 error page of its own -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="App_Data/Dependencies" />
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Deployment" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
            <add invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" name="Microsoft® SQL Server® Compact 4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Under the `<system.web>` section of the web.config, make sure you have an entry for sitemap.xml inside the `<httpHandlers>` block:

```
<httpHandlers>
    <!-- see below -->
    <clear />
    <add path="robots.txt" verb="GET" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
    <add path="SiteMap.xml" verb="GET" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
    <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Also make sure you have an entry in system.webserver/handlers that allows sitemap.xml:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Script,Read">
    <!-- clear all handlers, prevents executing code file extensions, prevents returning any file contents -->
    <clear/>
    <add name="Robots" path="robots.txt" verb="GET" modules="StaticFileModule" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
    <add name="SiteMap" path="SiteMap.xml" verb="GET" modules="StaticFileModule" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
    <!-- Return 404 for all requests via managed handler. The url routing handler will substitute the mvc request handler when routes match. -->
    <add name="NotFound" path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" requireAccess="Script"/>
</handlers>
```

These mods allow static files like sitemap.xml to be served publicly.

Comment: Can you paste your web.config. What happens when you to access sitemap.xml? WHat url are you trying to access it at?

Comment: Okay. Added, sorry about formatting but don't know hot to do it

Comment: You added a forward slash in both sitemap.xml entries in the web.config. Try entering it without the forward slash.

Comment: Fixed that and still get 403. There is a small padlock on my sitemap xml in Web Mtrix, could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Not sure, i haven't sued Web Matrix.

Comment: @Mr1159pm, you've missed `accessPolicy="Script,Read"`. I'm not sure, but this might cause the problem.

Comment: I had only "<handlers accessPolicy="Script">"  but that needed to be Script,Read instead of Script only.

Answer (score 5):

I personally prefer to use [Advanced Sitemap](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.WebAdvanced.Sitemap) module to generate sitemaps. It also takes care about `sitemap.xml` file accesibillity. You can take a look at it's sources and most likely you will find an answer on your question.

Comment: I looked into before but it only works with 1.4. Thanks for the tip tho!

Comment: I've upgraded my website today from Orchard 1.4.0 to 1.5.1, and the module works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

To add the robots.txt the httpHandlers are not necessary, because Orchard is in Integrated mode. Set in the Orchard web.config in  the handlers part to script,read:

```
<handlers accessPolicy="Script,Read">
```

and add after the `<clear/>` part these two lines:

```
<add name="Robots" path="robots.txt" verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read"/>
<add name="Sitemap" path="sitemap.xml" verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read"/>
```

I'm using Orchard 1.7.2

Answer (score 0):

If somebody's looking this question to figure out how to setup `robots.txt` only (without a `sitemap.xml`) then you could use a simple Orchard [Robots Module](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.SH.Robots). It gives an easy way to set `robots.txt` contents without editing `web.config` or whatsoever.